# Decompiling exe to python source code

Tags: python, decompile, byte-code

I've recently tried to decompile a .exe to .py source code. It partly went well as the majority of the .pyc got translated into python code but partly also failed. Like the following part:

```
--- This code section failed: ---

 L. 128       0_2  SETUP_LOOP        13710  'to 13710'
              4_0  COME_FROM         13706  '13706'
                4  LOAD_FAST                'self'
                6  LOAD_ATTR                _Worker__abort
                8  LOAD_CONST               True
               10  COMPARE_OP               !=
            12_14  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 13708  'to 13708'
```

Now my questions are:

1. What can cause such a decompiling error? The .exe is working.
2. What can I do to translate the rest of the failed decompiled byte-code to get the full source code?
3. Is there a place where I can find the construction of such byte-code to source code? Even though it would take a lot of time I could try to manually convert it.
   Any tips or ideas?

Thanks for reading

Comment: what tool are you using?

Comment: I used uncompyle6 and decompile3, both showing the same result.